# ng-repeat with error message alignment

Tags: css, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a ng-repeat control having textbox, textarea, and a delete image icon. I am having a required validator added for the textbox , textarea. Once the span error message is shown, the alignment is getting distorted. 
Below is the code used:

```
<div class="row">
                  <div class="form-group ">
                      <label class="form-group col-md-3">Language</label>
                      <label class="form-group col-md-4">Title</label>
                      <label class="form-group col-md-5">Description</label>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                  <div>
                      <div ng-repeat="Descriptions in testsWithDescription ">
                          <div class="form-group col-md-2 top-Margin-language">
                              <label ng-model="Descriptions.Language">{{Descriptions.Language}}</label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group col-md-4 top-Margin-Title">
                              <input type="text" maxlength="150" class="form-control input-md" required="" name="titleValidate_{{$index}}" ng-model="Descriptions.Title" />
                              <span style="color:red" ng-show="submitted == true && mainForm.titleValidate_{{$index}}.$error.required">Title is required</span> 
                          </div>

                          <div class="form-group col-md-5">
                              <textarea maxlength="500" class="form-control input-md noresize" required="" name="descriptionValidate_{{$index}}" noresize="" ng-model="Descriptions.Description"></textarea>
                              <span style="color:red" ng-show="submitted == true && mainForm.descriptionValidate_{{$index}}.$error.required">Description is required</span>
                          </div>

                          <div class="form-group col-md-1">
                              <a style="cursor:pointer">
                                  <img ng-src="{{DeleteIcon_url}}" alt="delete image" ng-click="($index == !selectedDeleteIcon) || testsWithDescription.splice($index,1)" ng-class="{'disabled': $first}" />
                              </a>

                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
```

How to set the alignment properly for span when using ng-repeat? Initial load the controls are aligned correct. If i remove any item in title or description, and click submit, the error messages are shown, but the UI is getting distorted.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide us a snipped or fiddle, so we can see what actually happens?

Comment: you should move your `ng-repeat` up to your `<div class="row">` as this will provide the "clearfix"'ing that bootstrap columns need in order to allow for the height change of the additional span. ie `<div class="row"  ng-repeat="Descriptions in testsWithDescription">`

Comment: Hi, I have provided the screen snippet.

Comment: Hi @haxxxton. Your solution solved the issue

Comment: Requesting Admin to Please set this question as Answered, the solution provide by @haxxxton has solved the issue. Currently I am not getting any icon to mark the question as answered. I have marked the comment as helpful.

Comment: @venkat14, easier for me to actually submit a solution, should have done it in the first place, appologies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap's `row` class includes "[clearfix](http://learnlayout.com/clearfix.html)"ing. This allows row's of varying height columns to consistently start at the left. Currently your html is using a nested `div` within your `row` class div as your repeating element. If you move the `ng-repeat` up to the `row` class div the clearfixing will take effect after each set of columns, and things should look visually as expected.

**Updated HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group ">
        <label class="form-group col-md-3">Language</label>
        <label class="form-group col-md-4">Title</label>
        <label class="form-group col-md-5">Description</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" ng-repeat="Descriptions in testsWithDescription ">
    <div class="form-group col-md-2 top-Margin-language">
        <label ng-model="Descriptions.Language">{{Descriptions.Language}}</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4 top-Margin-Title">
        <input type="text" maxlength="150" class="form-control input-md" required="" name="titleValidate_{{$index}}" ng-model="Descriptions.Title" />
        <span style="color:red" ng-show="submitted == true && mainForm.titleValidate_{{$index}}.$error.required">Title is required</span> 
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
        <textarea maxlength="500" class="form-control input-md noresize" required="" name="descriptionValidate_{{$index}}" noresize="" ng-model="Descriptions.Description"></textarea>
        <span style="color:red" ng-show="submitted == true && mainForm.descriptionValidate_{{$index}}.$error.required">Description is required</span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-1">
        <a style="cursor:pointer">
        <img ng-src="{{DeleteIcon_url}}" alt="delete image" ng-click="($index == !selectedDeleteIcon) || testsWithDescription.splice($index,1)" ng-class="{'disabled': $first}" />
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution provided by @haxxxton is the answer, which is:
you should move your ng-repeat up to your  as this will provide the "clearfix"'ing that bootstrap columns need in order to allow for the height change of the additional span. ie `<div class="row" ng-repeat="Descriptions in testsWithDescription">`